# SharePoint 2010 database migration to SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I planned to start the migration from SP2010 to SP2013 kindly share to me the to perform the steps to upgrade databases from SharePoint 2010 Products to SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon your environment, Here are steps.

- build a SharePoint 2013 farm
- Create and configure the Web Applications( Now, if you are on classic web app in 2010 then you have to make decision when you want convert the app to claims based...in 2010 or 2013)[Migrate from classic-mode to claims-based authentication in SharePoint 2013.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx)
- if you have any Customization(solutions, weboart, features etc), upgrade and deploy them into SharePoint 2013
- Now copy the database to SharePoint 2013 SQL server.
- Run the `[Test-SPContentDatabase][1]` against the content db and check if there is any issue. If any then fix it
- Now Mount the Content DB to Web application using [Mount-SPContentDatabase.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607581.aspx)
- Verify upgrade for the first database, check the upgrade logs
- Testing
- Now you have to upgrade the site collection 2013. [Upgrade site collections to SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219474.aspx)
- You have to run the Full search crawl, Full user Profile Sync.

Answer (score 0):

This [article at Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483.aspx) covers the whole process in step-by-step manner.

---

Usually `Test-SPContentDatabase` for making sure that there are no errors and handleable amount of warnings in log is enough if the 2010 farm has no 3rd-party solutions that require separate planning. Then `Mount-SPContentDatabase` and the rest is handled in UI.

There was a very [nice tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chandru/archive/2012/03/11/making-use-of-test-spcontentdatabase-generated-output.aspx) to convert `Test-SPContentDatabase`'s output to action lists.

Answer (score 0):

Above suggestions looks good to get this job done. As a workaround create a site collection in SharePoint 2013, detach the newly created content database and then attach the 2010 content database to the site collection. SharePoint 2013 will upgrade it for you. The process is explained [here](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/cory-granata/how-to-upgrade-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013-using-database-attach/)

Also get help from this step by step [guide](http://www.lepide.com/blog/step-by-step-guide-to-migrate-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013/) to Migrate from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013.